# Audit history of sql child table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, rowversion

I'm recording all insert and update on `TaskDetail` table using a trigger,Now I want to assign multiple staff to a task, But if staff id stored in different child table how can I track audit history, I have considered storing staff id as comma separated values but child table is always a good option.

In TaskStaff table multiple staff will have same taskId

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TaskDetail_History_Trigger]
ON [dbo].[TaskDetail]
FOR Insert,UPDATE
AS

INSERT INTO TaskHistory SELECT * FROM inserted
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProductionDetail] ENABLE TRIGGER [Task_History_Trigger]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TaskDetail](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[StaffId] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductionDetail_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [Id] ASC
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TaskHistory](
[HistoryId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Id] [int]  NOT NULL,
[StaffId] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductionDetail_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [Id] ASC
)


 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TaskStaff](
  [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [TaskId] [int] NOT NULL,
  [StaffId] [int] NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductionDetailStaff] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [Id] ASC
)
```

Comment: *I have considered storing staff id as comma separated values* Now you have bunch of problems. You should start with database design first.

Comment: I'm not using comma separated values just mentioned audit can be achieved using comma separated values.

Comment: You shouldn't consider this - you should eliminate it.

Comment: `But if staff id stored in different child table` what is the name of the  `child table` ?

Comment: TaskStaff is name of staff table, After inserting Task staff id will be saved into TaskStaff table with TaskId so its possible to have multiple staff